# Program will exit the loop even if wrong input

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner and learning C#.

I'm trying to do my homework, but got stuck. My program will exit the loop even if I type wrong input.

This is my code:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int lastYear = 0, thisYear = 0, totalRev;

        while (lastYear >= 0 && lastYear <= 30)
        {
            WriteLine("Enter number contestants last year >> ");
            lastYear = int.Parse(ReadLine());
            lastYear++;
        }

        WriteLine("Number must be between 0 and 30");
        WriteLine("Enter number contestants last year >> ");

        while (thisYear >= 0 && thisYear <= 30)
        {
            WriteLine("Enter num contestants this year >> ");
            thisYear = int.Parse(ReadLine());
        }

        WriteLine("Number must be between 0 and 30");

        totalRev = thisYear * 25;
        WriteLine($"last year's competition has {lastYear} conts, and this year's has {thisYear} conts " +
            "\nRevnue expected this year is {totalRev.ToString("c")} ");

        if (thisYear > lastYear && thisYear <= (lastYear * 2))
            WriteLine("The competition is bigger than ever!");
        else if (thisYear < lastYear)
            WriteLine("A tighter race this year! Come out and cast our vote!!");
        else if (thisYear > lastYear * 2)
            WriteLine("The competition is more than twice as big this year!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for....the **[Step Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2015)**

Comment: I've removed the `visual-studio` tag because this is a code question, and not a question about the Visual Studio IDE (which is what that tag is for).

Comment: `even if i type wrong input.` Can you share us an example of `wrong input`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you've mixed up your loop conditions. Your current code says:

> *"while last year is greater than or equal to zero and less than or equal to 30 (a valid value), keep asking for a number"*

What you want it to say is:

> *"while last year is less than zero or greater than 30 (an invalid value), keep asking for a number"*

The following code snipped should resolve the issue. Note I added a `bool firstLoop = true` variable so we don't show an error message the first time, and I've also set the initial values to *invalid* values, so the loop condition runs at least once:

```
int lastYear = -1, thisYear = -1, totalRev;

bool firstLoop = true;

while (lastYear < 0 || lastYear > 30)
{
    if (firstLoop == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Number must be from 0 to 30:. Please try again.");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Enter number contestants last year (0 - 30) >> ");
    lastYear = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    firstLoop = false;
}

firstLoop = true;

while (thisYear < 0 || thisYear > 30)
{
    if (firstLoop == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Number must be from 0 to 30:. Please try again.");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Enter number contestants this year (0 - 30) >> ");
    thisYear = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    firstLoop = false;
}
```

---

Looking at that code, however, we see there's a lot of repetition. In fact it's the exact same except for the message we're sending to the user and the variable we're testing/setting. This means it's a good candidate to be pulled out into a method of it's own.

It would be great if we had a method that we could pass in a string (which it would display to the user), and we could pass the minimum and maximum valid values, and it would return the user input for us!

We could have the code in the method body run in loop, and can use [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) to validate the user's input. `int.TryParse` takes in a string argument and an integer output parameter, returns true if the string can be converted to an integer, and sets the output parameter to the value. This is handy because we can use the return value to test if the input was a valid integer, and we can use the output parameter to test if it was within the acceptable range:

```
private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);

    int result;

    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) || 
        result < minValue || 
        result > maxValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: number must be from " + minValue + " to " + maxValue);
        Console.Write(prompt);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now with this method in place our main code is **GREATLY** simplified:

```
int lastYear = GetIntFromUser("Enter number contestants last year (0 - 30) >> ", 0, 30);
int thisYear = GetIntFromUser("Enter number contestants this year (0 - 30) >> ", 0, 30);
int totalRev = thisYear * 25;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `int.Parse` when user input is required, what if you type in something that's not an int? Bam! the computer doesn't know what you want, can't figure it out, then throws an exception.

Use instead [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation
>   succeeded.

Your programming is probably exiting because `int.Parse` is throwing an `ArgumentException` and exiting instantly when there is invalid input

A better pattern would be

```
while (thisYear >= 0 && thisYear <= 30)
{
    WriteLine("Enter num contestants this year >> ");
    while(!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out thisYear))
       WriteLine("OMG you had one job! try again");
}
```

Anyway this is just an example, I'll leave the details up to you.

Lastly, you really should have a look at this:

[Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2015)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of improvements. I'll encapsulate the following code into a separate method.

```
void GetYearInput(ref int year)
{
    while (lastYear >= 0 && lastYear <= 30)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number contestants last year >> ");
        lastYear = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        lastYear++;
    }
}
```

// Change the method as per your needs.
Also, for int.Parse, I'll use int.TryParse like below:

```
bool ifSuccess = int.TryParse(val, out result);
```

Mind you, if val is an invalid input, result will be 0. So, its important to check for ifSuccess.

You can change your methodname to GetValidYear or IsValidYear().

Also, may not be much relevant here, but for multiple if's, I would rather have nested if's:

```
if (thisYear > lastYear)
{
    if (thisYear <= (lastYear * 2))
    {}
    else if (thisYear > lastYear * 2)
    {}
    else {}
}
else if (thisYear < lastYear)
{}
else if(thisYear == lastYear) {}
```

Please avoid duplicating, copy/paste code and Refactor when necessary. Small maintainable methods are easy to test, maintain bla bla.

More on [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) and [out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out) is here.